# How to turn off the difference between page margins in a template

Tags: xetex, margins, double-sided

The following is  the `.cls` file of a Journal which I want to use to format my paper.
The formatting is  in a way that the margins are different for odd and even pages. I do not want this feature and want the margins to be equivalent for all pages. I remove all the lines containing the words "odd" and "even" since I suppose  those are the ones related to this formatting. But nothing changes. Could you please help. What should be changed in this code so the margins are  indifferent?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% --> THE CLASS OPTION MATERIAL
%% --> THE CLASS PRESENTATION MATERIAL
%% --> THE SECTIONING MATERIAL
%% --> THE METRIC DATA
%% --> THE TOP MATTER MATERIAL
%----  (A) The MAKETITLE command and its components
%----  (B) Preparing the MAKETITLE components
%          -1-   Heading
%          -2-   Title and Running Title
%          -3-   Authors and Running authors
%          -4-   Date
%          -5-   Subject Class
%          -6-   Resume
%          -7-   Abstract
%          -8-   Address (\address, given after the \author command)
%          -9-   Thanks  (given after the title: \thanks)
%% --> MISCELLANEOUS
%% --> MESSAGES
%% --> VARIOUS MACROS
%----  (A) LATIN ABBREVIATIONS
%----  (B) REFERENCES
%----  (C) NEWTHEOREM AND ENVIRONMENTS
%----  (D) MATHEMATICS
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> THE CLASS OPTION MATERIAL
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\ProvidesClass{md}[]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{amsart}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> THE CLASS PRESENTATION MATERIAL
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\LoadClass[reqno]{amsart}[1996/10/24]
\RequirePackage{cite}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> THE SECTIONING MATERIAL
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\section{\@startsection{section}{1}\z@{1.2\linespacing\@plus\linespacing}%
{\linespacing} {\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\scshape\centering}}
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}\z@{\linespacing\@plus.8\linespacing}%
{.8\linespacing}{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\scshape}}
\def\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}\z@{.7\linespacing\@plus.5\linespacing}%
{.5\linespacing}{\normalfont\itshape}}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}\z@\z@{-\fontdimen2\font}\normalfont}
\def\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{5}\z@\z@{-\fontdimen2\font}\normalfont}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> THE METRIC DATA
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\setlength\oddsidemargin {15pt}\setlength\evensidemargin{15pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{125mm}\setlength{\textheight}{190mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{18pt}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> THE TOP MATTER MATERIAL
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
% =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   
%----  (A) The MAKETITLE command and its components
\def\@maketitle{%
  \normalfont\normalsize
  \let\@makefnmark\relax \let\@thefnmark\relax
  \global\def\shorttitle{\@MSSG@RNNGTTL}
  \global\def\shortauthors{\@MSSG@RNNGTHR}
  \@mkboth{\@nx\shortauthors}{\@nx\shorttitle}%
  \global\topskip42\p@\relax
  \@SKIP@Aa
  %\vbox{\hbox to\hsize{{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont{\bf\@NMJRNL@E}}\hfill%
  %{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont\@JRNL@X}}
  %\hbox to\hsize{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont{\@NMJRNL@F}\hfill}}
  \vbox{\hbox to\hsize{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont{\bf\@NMJRNL@E}\hfill}%
  \hbox to\hsize{\fontsize{8}{9}\selectfont{\@JRNL@X}\hfill}}
  \@SKIP@Ab
  \@setdate
  \@settitle
  \@setauthors
  \@seteditor
  \@setabstract
  \@setkeywords
  \@setsubjclass
  \@setresume
  \normalsize
  \if@titlepage\newpage\else\dimen@34\p@\advance\dimen@-\baselineskip\vskip\dimen@\relax\fi
  \gdef\thanks##1{\relax}\gdef\address##1{\relax}
}% end \@maketitle
% =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   
%----  (B) Preparing the MAKETITLE components
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -1-   Heading
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@SKIP@Aa{\vspace*{-1.5cm}}%
\def\@SKIP@Ab{\vspace*{1.5cm}}%
\def\@NMJRNL@E{{Management Decision}}%
\def\@JRNL@X{{Will be set by the publisher}}%
\def\idline#1page#2{\global\def\@JRNL@X{#1}\setcounter{page}{#2}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -2-   Title and Running Title
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}\fontsize{11}{15}\selectfont\bfseries
    \uppercasenonmath\@title\@title\@thnks@i\@thnks@ii\@thnks@iii\@thnks@iv\@thnks@v
\ifnum\the\@c@thnks@=0\else\footnote{\box\@b@thnks@}\fi
\end{center}}
\newbox\@b@rnngttl
\def\runningtitle#1{\setbox\@b@rnngttl=\hbox{\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont\rm\uppercase{#1}}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -3-   Authors and Running authors
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@setauthors{\begingroup\trivlist
  \centering\footnotesize \@topsep30\p@\relax\advance\@topsep by -\baselineskip
  \item\relax\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\scshape\@@th@rs\ignorespaces
  \footnote{\box\@b@ddrss@}\endtrivlist\endgroup}
\def\email#1{{e-mail: \tt#1}}
\newbox\@b@rnngthr
\def\runningauthors#1{\setbox\@b@rnngthr=\hbox{#1}%
\global\def\@rnngthrs{\fontsize{7}{9}\selectfont\rm\uppercase{#1}}}
\newcount\@c@thr@\@c@thr@=0
\def\author#1{\global\advance\@c@thr@ by 1
          \global\expandafter\edef\csname @thr@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{#1}
          \global\expandafter\edef\csname @Mthr@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{\uppercase{#1}}
          \global\expandafter\def\csname @ddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{}
          \global\expandafter\def\csname @scndddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{}
          \global\expandafter\def\csname @smddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{}}%\author
%    Elaborating the two author lists (First page and heading)
\newcount\@y\newcount\@x
\def\@cnjctn{\ifnum\the\@c@thr@=1\null\else{{\ and\ }}\fi}
\def\@Mcnjctn{\ifnum\the\@c@thr@=1\null\else{{\ AND\ }}\fi}
\def\@@th@rs{\@x=0\global\@y=\@c@thr@\global\advance\@y by -1
\loop\advance\@x by 1
\ifnum\the\@x<\the\@y\csname  @thr@\romannumeral\@x\endcsname\ignorespaces
            ${}^{\csname  @ddrss@\romannumeral\@x\endcsname
                 \csname  @smddrss@\romannumeral\@x\endcsname
                 \csname  @scndddrss@\romannumeral\@x\endcsname}$,
\repeat
\csname  @thr@\romannumeral\@y\endcsname\ignorespaces
            ${}^{\csname  @ddrss@\romannumeral\@y\endcsname
                 \csname  @smddrss@\romannumeral\@y\endcsname
                 \csname  @scndddrss@\romannumeral\@y\endcsname}$\@cnjctn
\csname  @thr@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname\ignorespaces
            ${}^{\csname  @ddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname
                 \csname  @smddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname
                 \csname  @scndddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname}$}%\@@th@rs
\def\M@@th@rs{\@x=0\global\@y=\@c@thr@\global\advance\@y by -1
\loop\advance\@x by 1
\ifnum\the\@x<\the\@y\csname  @Mthr@\romannumeral\@x\endcsname,
\repeat
\csname  @Mthr@\romannumeral\@y\endcsname\@Mcnjctn
\csname  @Mthr@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname}%\M@@th@rs
\def\@qq#1#2{\vrule height#1 depth#2 width0pt}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -4-   Date and editor 
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\let\@date\@empty
\def\@setdate{\noindent\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont\footnote{\@date\@addpunct.}}
%
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\newcommand{\communicated}{Communicated by}
\newbox\editorbox
\def\editor#1{\global\setbox\editorbox=\vtop{%
\centering\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\communicated\ #1\@qq{0pt}{4pt}}}
\def\@seteditor{\skip@30\p@\advance\skip@-\lastskip\advance\skip@-\baselineskip \vskip\skip@
  \ifvoid\editorbox\else\centering\box\editorbox\fi}

%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -5-   Subject Class
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\renewcommand{\subjclassname}{Mathematics Subject Classification}
\newbox\subjbox
\def\subjclass#1{\global\setbox\subjbox=\vtop{\advance\hsize by-72pt
\noindent\textbf{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\subjclassname.\ }\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont#1\@qq{0pt}{4pt}}}
\def\@setsubjclass{\skip@20\p@\advance\skip@-\lastskip\advance\skip@-\baselineskip \vskip\skip@
  \ifvoid\subjbox\else\moveright 3pc \box\subjbox\fi}  
%
\newbox\@b@kwrds
\def\keywords#1{\global\setbox\@b@kwrds\vtop{\advance\hsize by-72pt    \noindent\textbf{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\@MSSG@KWRD@0K}\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont#1\@qq{0pt}{4pt}}}
\def\@setkeywords{\skip@20\p@\advance\skip@-\lastskip\advance\skip@-\baselineskip \vskip\skip@
\ifvoid\@b@kwrds\else\moveright 3pc\box\@b@kwrds\fi}
%\def\@setkeywords{\ifvoid\@b@kwrds\else\footnote{\box\@b@kwrds}\fi}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -6-   Resume
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\newbox\resumebox
\newenvironment{resume}{\ifx\maketitle\relax\ClassWarning{\@classname}{\@MSSG@CLSSWRNG}\fi
  \global\setbox\resumebox=\vtop\bgroup\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont\advance \hsize -6pc
  \trivlist 
    \labelsep.5em\item[\hskip\labelsep{\scshape\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\bf R\'esum\'e}.]}
{\endtrivlist\egroup\ifx\@setresume\relax \@setresumea \fi}
\def\@setresume{\@setresumea\global\let\@setresume\relax}
\def\@setresumea{\skip@20\p@\advance\skip@-\lastskip\advance\skip@-\baselineskip \vskip\skip@
  \ifvoid\resumebox\else\moveright 3pc \box\resumebox\fi}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -7-   Abstract
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\newbox\abstractbox
\renewenvironment{abstract}{\ifx\maketitle\relax\ClassWarning{\@classname}{\@MSSG@CLSSWRNG}\fi
  \global\setbox\abstractbox=\vtop\bgroup\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont 
  \advance \hsize -6pc
  \trivlist 
    \labelsep.5em\item[\hskip\labelsep{\scshape\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\bf Abstract}.]}
{\endtrivlist\egroup\ifx\@setabstract\relax \@setabstracta \fi}
\def\@setabstract{\@setabstracta\global\let\@setabstract\relax}
\def\@setabstracta{\skip@20\p@ \advance\skip@-\lastskip \advance\skip@-\baselineskip \vskip\skip@
  \ifvoid\abstractbox{\hbox to\hsize{\kern3pc\fontsize{10}{12}
          \selectfont\bf \hbox to55pt{Abstract\hfill}\qquad\@MSSG@BSTRCT\hfill}}
    \else\moveright 3pc \box\abstractbox \fi}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%                Address         (\address, given after the \author command)
%         -8-    Same Address    (\sameaddress, given after the \author command)
%                Second Address  (\secondaddress, given after the \author command)
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@spc{\kern1pt}\def\@spcc{\kern2pt}
\newcount\@c@ddrss@\newbox\@b@ddrss@
%
\def\@dd@ddrss@#1{%
\global\setbox51=\vbox{\advance\hsize by-12pt\unvbox\@b@ddrss@
  \vtop{\footnotesize\noindent{${}^{\the\@c@ddrss@}$\ }\@qq{10pt}{0pt}\textrm{#1}}}
  \global\setbox\@b@ddrss@=\vbox{\unvbox51}}%
%
\def\@dd@scndddrss@#1{%
\global\setbox51=\vbox{\advance\hsize by-12pt\unvbox\@b@ddrss@
  \vtop{\footnotesize\noindent{${}^{\the\@c@ddrss@}$\ }\@qq{10pt}{0pt}\textrm{#1}}}
  \global\setbox\@b@ddrss@=\vbox{\unvbox51}}
%
\def\address#1{\global\advance\@c@ddrss@ by 1\@dd@ddrss@{#1}
  \expandafter\edef\csname @ddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{\@spc\number\@c@ddrss@}}
\def\secondaddress#1{\global\advance\@c@ddrss@ by 1\@dd@ddrss@{#1}
  \expandafter\edef\csname @scndddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname%
{,\@spcc\number\@c@ddrss@}}%\secondaddress#1
\def\sameaddress#1{\expandafter\edef\csname @smddrss@\romannumeral\@c@thr@\endcsname{\@spc{}#1}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%          -9-   Thanks  (given in the title: \thanks)
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@rmnnmrl#1{\ifcase#1\null\or*\or**\or***\or****\or*****\else\@MSSG@THNKS\fi}
\def\@thnks@i{}\def\@thnks@ii{}\def\@thnks@iii{}\def\@thnks@iv{}\def\@thnks@v{}
\newcount\@c@thnks@\newbox\@b@thnks@
\def\@dd@thnks@#1{%
\global\setbox50=\vbox{\advance\hsize by-12pt\unvbox\@b@thnks@
  \vtop{\noindent\footnotesize{${}^{\@rmnnmrl\@c@thnks@}$\ }\@qq{10pt}{0pt}\textit{#1}\hfill}}
\global\setbox\@b@thnks@=\vbox{\unvbox50}}%
\def\thanks#1{\global\advance\@c@thnks@ by 1\@dd@thnks@{#1}%
\global\expandafter\edef\csname @thnks@\romannumeral\@c@thnks@\endcsname{%
\ifnum\the\@c@thnks@=1\@spcc${}^{\@rmnnmrl\@c@thnks@}$\else$^{,\@spcc\@rmnnmrl\@c@thnks@}$\fi}}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> MISCELLANEOUS
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\DeclareRobustCommand*\cal{\@fontswitch\relax\mathcal}
%
\renewcommand\normalsize{\@xsetfontsize\normalsize 6%
  \@adjustvertspacing \let\@listi\@listI 
  \abovedisplayskip 11pt \@plus2pt \@minus2pt
  \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip}
\renewcommand\Huge{\@setfontsize\Huge\@viiipt{9}}
%
\def\ps@firstpage{\ps@plain
  \def\@oddfoot{\hfill{\scriptsize \copyright\ }}%
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot\def\@oddhead{\null\hss}
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead}% in case an article starts on a left-hand page
%
\def\ps@headings{\ps@empty
%  \def\@evenhead{\normalfont\scriptsize\llap{\normalsize\thepage\kern-4pt}\hfil\scriptsize\leftmark{}{}\hfil}%
%  \def\@oddhead{\normalfont\scriptsize\hfil\rightmark{}{}\hfil\rlap{\kern-4pt\normalsize{\thepage}}}%
  \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil\leftmark\hfil\ }%
  \def\@oddhead{\hfil\ \rightmark\hfil\thepage}%
  \let\@mkboth\markboth}
\def\ps@myheadings{\ps@headings \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo}\pagestyle{headings}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> MESSAGES
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\def\@MSSG@THNKS{At most 5 thanks allowed}
\def\@MSSG@CLSSWRNGRSM{Resume should precede \protect\maketitle\space in AMS documentclasses; reported}
\def\@MSSG@CLSSWRNGBSTRCT{Abstract should precede \protect\maketitle\space in AMS documentclasses; 
           reported}
\def\@MSSG@KWRD{{WARNING:  --- Give at least one key words ---}}
\def\@MSSG@KWRD@0K{{Keywords:\ }}
\def\@MSSG@SBJCTCLSS{{--- Give AMS classification codes  ---}}
\def\@MSSG@RSM{{WARNING:  --- Il est obligatoire de donner un r\'esum\'e en fran\c cais! ---}}
\def\@MSSG@BSTRCT{{WARNING:  --- An English abstract is mandatory! ---}}
%\def\@MSSG@DT{{(The dates will be set by the publisher)}}
\def\@MSSG@DT{{The date should precede $\backslash${\tt maketitle} in AMS documentclasses; reported}}
%\def\@MSSG@DTR{{(The editor will be set by the publisher)}}
\def\@MSSG@DTR{}
%% September 2002
\def\@MSSG@RNNGTTL{\uppercase{}}
\def\@MSSG@RNNGTHR{\uppercase{}}
%
\def\@date{\@MSSG@DT}
\def\@editor{\@MSSG@DTR}
\def\@subjclass#1{\@MSSG@SBJCTCLSS}
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% --> VARIOUS MACROS
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%----  (A) LATIN ABBREVIATIONS
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\cf{\emph{cf.\/}}\def\ie{\emph{i.e.\/}}\def\etc{\emph{etc\/}}
\def\apriori{\emph{a priori\/}}\def\afortiori{\emph{a fortiori\/}}
\def\loccit{\emph{a loc. cit.\/}}\def\etal{\emph{et al.\/}}
\def\vg{\emph{v.g.\/}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%----  (B) REFERENCES
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\@Rref#1{\hbox{\rm \ref{#1}}}
\def\Rref#1{\@Rref{#1}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%----  (C) NEWTHEOREM AND ENVIRONMENTS
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%-------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
%-------------------
\newtheorem{thrm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{insight}{Numerical Insight}[section]
\newtheorem{lmm}[thrm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{crllr}{Corollary}[section]
\newtheorem{prpstn}{Proposition}[section]
\newtheorem{crtrn}[thrm]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{lgrthm}[thrm]{Algorithm}
%------------------------
\theoremstyle{definition}
%------------------------
\newtheorem{dfntn}[thrm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{cnjctr}[thrm]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{xmpl}[thrm]{Example}
\newtheorem{prblm}[thrm]{Problem}
\newtheorem{rmrk}[thrm]{Remark}
\newtheorem{nt}[thrm]{Note}
\newtheorem{clm}[thrm]{Claim}
\newtheorem{smmr}[thrm]{Summary}
\newtheorem{cs}[thrm]{Case}
\newtheorem{bsrvtn}[thrm]{Observation}

%
%-------------------
\theoremstyle{plain}
%-------------------
\newenvironment{acknowledgement}{\par\addvspace{17pt}\small\rmfamily\trivlist\item[]}%
{\endtrivlist\addvspace{6pt}}
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
%----  (D) MACROS FOR MATHEMATICS
%................ ................ ................ ................  ................
\def\xQuaternion{\mathbb{H}} \def\xC{\mathbb{C}} \def\xR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\xQ{\mathbb{Q}} \def\xZ{\mathbb{Z}} \def\xN{\mathbb{N}}
\def\xP{\mathbb{P}} \def\xA{\mathbb{A}}
%--
\def\xCzero{{\rm C}^{0}}
\def\xCone{{\rm C}^{1}} 
\def\xCtwo{{\rm C}^{2}} 
\def\xCinfty{{\rm C}^{\infty}} 
\def\xCn#1{{\rm C}^#1}
%--
\def\xHzero{{\rm H}^{0}}
\def\xHone{{\rm H}^{1}}
\def\xHtwo{{\rm H}^{2}} 
\def\xHinfty{{\rm H}^{\infty}}
\def\xHn#1{{\rm H}^#1}
%
\def\xWzero{{\rm W}^{0}}
\def\xWone{{\rm W}^{1}}
\def\xWtwo{{\rm W}^{2}} 
\def\xWinfty{{\rm W}^{\infty}}
\def\xWn#1{{\rm W}^#1}
%
\def\xLzero{{\rm L}^{0}}
\def\xLone{{\rm L}^{1}}
\def\xLtwo{{\rm L}^{2}} 
\def\xLinfty{{\rm L}^{\infty}} 
\def\xLn#1{{\rm L}^#1}
%-- 
\def\xDif{{\rm D}}
\def\xdif{\,{\rm d}}
%-- 
\def\xdrv#1#2{\frac{{\rm d}#1}{{\rm d}#2}}%  "d#1 over d#2"
\def\xDrv#1#2{\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}#2}#1}%  "d   over d#2  #1"
%--
\def\xker{\mathop{\rm ker\,}\nolimits}
\def\xcoker{\mathop{\rm coker\,}\nolimits}
\def\xim{\mathop{\rm im\,}\nolimits}
\def\xcoim{\mathop{\rm coim\,}\nolimits}
\def\xdim{\mathop{\rm dim\,}\nolimits}
\def\xcodim{\mathop{\rm codim\,}\nolimits}
\def\xtr{\mathop{\rm tr\,}\nolimits}
\def\xHom{\mathop{\rm Hom\,}\nolimits}
\def\xExt{\mathop{\rm Ext\,}\nolimits}
\def\xTor{\mathop{\rm Tor\,}\nolimits}
%--
\def\xGL{\mathop{\rm GL\,}\nolimits}
\def\xSL{\mathop{\rm SL\,}\nolimits}
\def\xPSL{\mathop{\rm PSL\,}\nolimits}
\def\xSO{\mathop{\rm SO\,}\nolimits}
\def\xSU{\mathop{\rm SU\,}\nolimits}
%
\def\xProof{
  \normalfont
  \medskip
  {\noindent\itshape Proof.\hspace*{6pt}\ignorespaces}}
%
\def\enddoc@text{\ifx\@empty\@translators \else\@settranslators\fi
  \ifon@line\noindent\quad \vfill\onlineLogo\fi}
%

\renewcommand\@pnumwidth{2.2em}
\renewcommand\@tocrmarg{2.2em}
\newcommand\@dotsep{1.5}
\newcommand{\l@titlecontent}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{0em}}
\newcommand{\entry}[3]{\contentsline{chapter}{\scshape #1}{}
\contentsline{titlecontent}{\sffamily\bfseries{#2\;}}{\textsf{#3}}}
%
%
\newif\ifon@line
\newcommand{\online}{\on@linetrue}
\on@linefalse
%
\newcommand{\onlineLogo}{
\begin{center}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{4.5cm}
\hrule \kern 4pt
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\hrule
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
}
%
\let\paragraphname\@empty
\endinput
```

Comment: Just to remind: if you are preparing to submit to that journal and the class file is the official template of that journal, then there is no need to change the format, including the page margins.

Comment: why use a journal class if you are not submitting to the journal?

Comment: probably you want to add oneside here:  `\LoadClass[oneside,reqno]{amsart}[1996/10/24]` but changing a journal class is not usually a good idea since it prevents it being used for the journal submissions.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ 
Because the journal I am submitting to did not provide a template and this was the closest to its already published papers. As a  reviewer myself, I assumed that the reviewers  would  be disturbed  by this formatting when scrolling down, since they have to scroll left and right from time to time.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your suggestion. It worked. I explained the reason in the above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is using `amsart` so you can load it with its `oneside` option by changing the line to say

```
\LoadClass[oneside,reqno]{amsart}[1996/10/24]
```